# Clarification on the definition of progressively measurable processes

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I am finding difficulties in becoming familiar with the definition of progressively measurable processes.

**Definition**
A stochastic process $X$ is called progressively measurable with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ if, for every $t$, $X\mid_{[0,t]\times\Omega}$ is $\mathcal{B}\left([0,t]\right)\otimes\mathcal{F}_{t}$-measurable, i.e.

$$
\left\{\left(s,\omega\right)\in\left[0,t\right]\times\Omega\mid X_{s}\left(\omega\right)\in H\right\}\in \mathcal{B}([0,t])\otimes\mathcal{F}_t,\quad H\in\mathcal{B}
$$

Which is, if any exists, the intuition behind this definition? Or is this just a technical requirement for proofs?

Comment: It's an assumption that ensures $X_\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable for stopping times $\tau$.

Comment: thanks, so If I understand it is not enough to be adapted. Is there a simple example of an $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted stochastic process and a stopping time $\tau$ such that $X_{\tau}$ is not $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$-measurable?